# Query with diff static values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to write a SQL like,

```
Select account,'AB' a from account_tbl rownum<5
Union
Select account,'CD' a from account_tbl rownum<5
```

Here accounts fetched from  1st query should not come in second query.

Comment: You need a right join instead of a union.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
Select account,
       (case when rownum < 5 then 'AB' else 'CD' end) as a
from account_tbl
where rownum < 9;
```

Answer (score -1):

BECAUSE THE SET OPERTORS (UNION,INTERSECT,MINUS) ALWAYS WORK WITH SAME COLUMN IN FIRST QUERY YOU WRITE 'AB' AND IN SECOND QUERY YOU WRITE 'CD' THAT'S WHY I DIDN'T WORK.
I THINK SO